# Use the LocalStorageAdapter, store settings in a single emberObject

Tags: ember.js

I am using the LSAdapter to store ember-object fetched from a non-restful api endpoint.
Works really great with the models I have created, and I am able to use the DS.Model very well.

We're now looking to introduce some app-wide settings, and I'd love to store these in a DS.Model as well to be able to use the two way data-binding in a simple way. The problem is I can't figure out how to use the Models, but only store and fetch one record.

Currently these are stored in an Ember.Object.

```
/**
* Settings is a object to store application-wide settings
*/
App.Settings  = Ember.Object.create({
    // Which navigation-application should we use on map-links, default to waze
    navigationApp: 'waze', // waze, google, apple
});
```

I watch these in some controllers, to detect whenever they change - and then sync them manually to localStorage:

```
Driver.HelpController = Ember.ObjectController.extend({

// Setup the options
navigationAppOptions: ['waze', 'google', 'apple'],

/**
 * Change the navigationApp variable in localStorage
 * whenever Driver.Settings.navigationApp changes
 * @return void
 */
changeNavigationApp: function () {
    // Set the navigationApp to localStorage to persist between reloads
    localStorage.setItem('navigationApp', Driver.Settings.navigationApp);
}.observes('Driver.Settings.navigationApp'),
});
```

What is best practice here?
We have around ~15 settings that changes on and off - and I'd love to have the benefit of two-way data-binding, without having to work directly with hard-coded localStorage items...